# How to Save Array Variables in a text file using Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, text

I have different meteorological variables which I was stored in Array as given below

```
    Pres=np.array(PRES)
    Temp=np.array(TEMP)
    Hght=np.array(HGHT)
    Dewp=np.array(DWPT)
    Relh=np.array(RELH)
    Drct=np.array(DRCT)
    Sknt=np.array(SKNT)
```

Now, I want to write these all variables in a **out.txt** file like given below

```
       PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   DRCT   SKNT
      832.0   1703   34.8   -4.2      8   3.38    205
      822.0   1812   32.8   -3.2     10   3.69    225
      792.7   2134   29.2   -5.2     10   3.29    285
```

For that, I have tried this method

```
    with open("out.txt", "w") as o:
        for line , row in zip(Pres, Hght, Temp, Dewp, Relh, Drct, Sknt):
           print("{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s}".format(line, *row, file=o)
```

But `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` is coming. Kindly suggest for same

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to just store this as a pandas df and then write that to a csv or txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to missing parenthesis:

```
with open("out.txt", "w") as o:
        for line , row in zip(Pres, Hght, Temp, Dewp, Relh, Drct, Sknt):
           print("{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s}".format(line, *row, file=o) <--- Here
```

Syntax Error Fix and arrays unpacking:

```
with open("out.txt", "w") as o:
        for row in zip(Pres, Hght, Temp, Dewp, Relh, Drct, Sknt):
           print("{:<7f},{:<7f},{:<7f},{:<7f},{:<7f},{:<7f},{:<7f}".format(*[float(x) for x in row]), file=o)
```

Unpack multiple arrays:

```
import random

a = list(range(3))
b = list(range(3))
c = list(range(3))

[random.shuffle(a), random.shuffle(b), random.shuffle(c)]

for r in zip(a, b, c):
    print("{0},{1},{2}".format(*row))
```

Output:

```
1,0,1
0,2,2
2,1,0
```

Comment: Error is coming after running earlier solution.`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: It's due to the fact that there are many arrays to be unpacked to `row`.

Comment: Is there any solution to pack all variables at same time??

Comment: Kindly provide any syntax or hint...!

Comment: @Addy Added an example for you. Regardless of the error in the post: there are 7 arrays that you are willing to format to the string, so use only `row` to contain them

Comment: @Addy Look at the updated code it writes the arrays to file

Comment: It works, but I'm not able to write it in a text file with spacing 7

Comment: Use `"{:<7f},{:<7f},{:<7f},{:<7f},{:<7f},{:<7f},{:<7f}"` to format floats with 7 digits percision @Addy.

Comment: I have used this float format, but `ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`

Comment: I tried with this also   `print("{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s},{:<7s}".format(*row))`, but again **IndexError: tuple index out of range**

Comment: Turns out your data is strings, check out the updated code @Addy

Comment: Thank you @Aviv Yaniv. It works with proper formatting. Thanks a lot.